# prolog sum list using atomic

Tags: prolog, sum, atomic, flatten

I am trying to perform a sumList function in prolog that takes the 
input: sumList([1,[2,3],[4],5],X). and returns X=15.

I understand how to sum a simple list and a list of lists(ie [1,2,3,4,5] & [[1,2,3],[4,5]]) but i am getting errors because i am not properly handing the multiple inner lists(because i do not yet know how to, i havent encountered this before), i was told i have to use atom or atomic by a college somehow but i haven't seen a clear example on how this is done.
any sml code i could translate or prolog code that could help me sum the list [1,[2,3],[4],5] would be greatly appericated.
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SWI Prolog (just not sure about ANSI) the `atomic(X)` predicate can tell you whether the X is list or a number (in your case). It can be used write the `sum` predicate by recursively calling itself when a list is encountered, or just add the element to a sum if a simple number:

```
sum([], 0).
sum([H|T], S) :-
    atomic(H),
    sum(T, S1),
    S is H + S1.
sum([H|T], S) :- 
    sum(H, S1),
    sum(T, S2),
    S is S1 + S2.
```

Comment: thanks so much! that is amazing i have been struggling trying to find any decent examples of atom or atomic(more then their general definitions) for half the afternoon. Yes i am working in SMI prolog.

Comment: i do not have the reputation to upvote @Eugene but i did accept the answer, i really appreciate the help in understanding atomic and the example.

Answer (score 0):

Prolog treats an [] as atomic. The implementation from [Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4253229/eugene-sh) doesn't handle the case when H is an empty list []. Checking if H is an empty list in the second clause solves the issue.

```
sum([], 0).
sum([H|T], S) :-
    atomic(H),
    H\==[], % fail incase H is an empty list 
    sum(T, S1),
    S is H + S1.
sum([H|T], S) :- 
    sum(H, S1),
    sum(T, S2),
    S is S1 + S2.
```